# Problem with the Tool Flags during the c++ module compilation

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-errors, compiler-flags

I'm trying to compile the module in Eclipse and generate the additional output disassembles

I've added these Tool Flags

```
-fverbose-asm -Wa,-adhln -save-temps=obj > %OutFile%.asm
```

But I receive this error

```
clang: error: unsupported argument '-adhln' to option 'Wa,'
```

Does anybody had a similar issue? If so please help

Many Thanks

Comment: Maybe clang's integrated assembler doesn't support those options? Have you tried `-no-integrated-as` ?

Comment: @Michael Unfortunately it did not helped. I've managed to solve the problem differently. I just left the: -save-temps=obj which generates me the AT&T syntax assemblies (but without relative addresses of instructions) So I simply used objdump to generate INTEL syntax assemblies with relative addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the target was to generate the assemblies with the instructions HEX and relative addresses

I was not able to do that using Eclipse >> Tool Flags so I simply left one flag:

```
-save-temps=obj
```

Which generates AT&T systax assemblies but without details like (instruction Hex or relative address)

But I've managed to generate INTEL syntax assemblies with all the details I need to debug my problem using objdump

```
objdump -d -M intel -S DMAProcesor.o > DMAProcessor.asm
```